# PHP: Click link and it echo's

Tags: php, html

Im still very new to PHP but this seems like its so simple to do but im stuck (it may be because im tired)
Anyway basically all I need it to do is echo out some text on the same page when I click a button.

I have a CSS styled button and this is what it looks like in just html:

```
<a href="#"  class="button">Get watching</a>
```

I now need that converted into PHP so when clicked it echos out some text.

Thank you very much,
Joe

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about how PHP works. PHP creates HTML on the server and then sends the HTML to the browser.

Comment: I think here you need JavaScript

Comment: juse Javascript for this. php is server-side. you will do somthing on client-side...

Comment: You cannot do this with PHP. You have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Or use a form with a button...check if it's POST and do something based on that ;)

Comment: Ahh I see im not very confident on Javascript :( Can someone answer this question with a javascript code?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onClick="showText()"  class="button">Get watching</a>
<p id="showText"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showText()
{
      document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML = "Some Text";
}
</script>
```